# Apache httpd is not restarting in centos

Tags: apache, centos6.5, zend-server-ce

I install **Zend server CE 5.6**. With that **Apache** is installed automatically. Now I want to restart Apache server then it is showing error

[click here for image to see exact error](http://www.tiikoni.com/tis/view/?id=55528d9)

any help

why i cannot restart apache httpd service.....?

Comment: check your httpd.conf file.

Comment: what changes i need to do in http.conf.

Answer (score 0):

Well you got some syntax error in httpd.conf and zedserver_php.conf. 
For libphp5.so, check if the user apache can access to usr/local/zend/lib/apache2/libphp5.so.
First look, I think you have some error in httpd.conf and zedserver_php.conf and that apache can't access to httpd.conf and zedserver_php.conf.